# Join query using two table with where condition in cake php?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

How we can write Join query using two table with where condition in cake php?

Comment: You (probably) shouldn't, you should use [CakePHP's associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can!!
check this if it would help you

```
$table = 'table_name';
    $query['conditions'] = array($table.'.entity_id' => $entity_id, $table.'.is_active' => 1);

        $query['fields'] = array('creator.first_name AS cf_name', 'creator.last_name AS cl_name', 'creator.email AS c_email', 'usr.first_name', 'usr.last_name',
            $table.'.id AS id', $table.'.guid', $table.'.updated_date',
            'usr.email AS email');

        // To do joining to get attribute with value
        $query['joins'] = array(
            array(
                    'table' => $this->user,
                    'alias' => 'usr',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array('usr.id = '.$table.'.user_id')
                ),
                array(
                    'table' => $this->user,
                    'alias' => 'creator',
                    'type' => 'INNER',
                    'conditions' => array('creator.id = '.$table.'.creator_id')
                ),
        );
        $query['order'] = array($table.'.updated_date' => 'DESC');

        // Cache implementation
        $result = $this->find('all', $query);
```

Comment: For more detailed reading on the subject, see here: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/nate/2009/01/21/quick-tip-doing-ad-hoc-joins-in-model-find